# .Net Regex.Escape not working properly?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which takes a string of character and builds them into an expression as a range. I use Regex.Escape (.net 3.5) to sanitize these strings so that there shouldn't be any control characters left. But it seems as though the Escape method isn't working as expected and won't escape closing `}` or `]` characters. Shouldn't it be escaping these? Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
string test = @"sdfz346gv][)(}{><";
string pattern = "[" + Regex.Escape(test) + "]+";
string input = "ffff{444}g";

if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Matched");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Matched");
}
```

The `pattern` string seems to have the value `[sdfz346gv]\[\)\(}\{><]+` and won't match `ffff{444}g` but as far as I'm concerned it should look like this `[sdfz346gv\]\[\)\(\}\{><]+` which is an expression that performs a differently and will match `ffff{444}g`. I could just replace `}` and `]` characters with `\}` and `\]` but are there any other characters that don't get escaped by this escape method? Can I rely on it?

Comment: I don't want it to escape the last `]` character, I want it to escape the penultimate one. Otherwise it changes the meaning of the expression. - edit sorry I see what you mean (typo in the question, have fixed) but the problem still remains.

Comment: Then edit your question. You clearly say "as far as I'm concerned it should look like this `[sdfz346gv]\[\)\(\}\{><\]+`", which is escaping the last `]`. What you actually want is `[sdfz346gv\]\[\)\(\}\{><]+`

Comment: We keep just missing each other :)

Comment: Just a friendly recommendation - Expresso (windows) is an amazing free tool to use for debugging regular expressions.  Helped me no end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx):

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes.

And

> While the Escape method escapes the straight opening bracket ([) and opening brace ({) characters, it does not escape their corresponding closing characters (] and }). In most cases, escaping these is not necessary. If a closing bracket or brace is not preceded by its corresponding opening character, the regular expression engine interprets it literally.

Comment: If that is the case then I suppose it's not really appropriate to concatenate escaped regex strings with regex that has control characters in it... This seems like it kind of defeats the purpose of escaping them in the first place!

Comment: @JonM: Regex metacharacters lose or change their meaning inside character classes. If you plan on putting a `Regex.Escape()`d string into a character class, you have to "manually" escape the `]` and `-` characters, too.

Comment: @JonM: It does seem like a really weird assumption by Microsoft that you don't need to escape the closing bracket or brace. The `in most cases` is only the case where there isn't another set of brackets or braces that aren't meant to be interpreted as literals. I think you are probably safe if you just do a simple replace of `]` and `}` with `\]` and `\}` before you create your regex pattern.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes I understand that, I just assumed that the escape method would escape the `]` character as it does with the `[` character.

Comment: @MattBurland: And don't forget the dash!

Comment: By the way, Python goes to the other extreme and escapes *every*  non-alphanumeric character :)